# Docker tomcat editing configuration files through dockerfile

Tags: tomcat, docker, containers, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a dockerfile and docker-compose like below, which is suppost to create an image of tomcat inside my container and edit the tomcat users so that I am able to access the manager gui.
The four files below are all in the same folder as where I run the *docker-compose up* command.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  tomcat:
    build: .
    container_name: development
    ports:
      - 8001:8080
    environment:
      - spring.profiles.active=development
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
    <user username="manager" password="pass" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="pass" roles="tomcat"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
   <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
</Context>
```

when I run the command *docker-compose up*, it generates the container with a tomcat image perfectly, but the existing tomcat-users.xml and context.xml didn't get overwritten. Any idea what I'm doing wrong to overwrite those two files?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Have you tried rebuilding the image with `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`? Also consider `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to check that the files are as expected

Comment: I'm also not able to reproduce. The image looks fine to me with the right files. As Jan Trienes mentioned I would try to use docker-compose up build to be sure the image is rebuilded.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I figured out what the issue was, explained in the answer below.

Comment: You should accept your own answer for this question if it is correct.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. The problem was that the user with which I was executing the build tasks did not have sufficient rights to write stuff in those folders.  What I did was add a *USER root* task to the Dockerfile so it executes all the commands as root.

My Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat
USER root
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Comment: It would seem to me that unless you add a `USER` before the final `CMD`, you will be running tomcat as `root` which poses a serious security risk. Is that not so?

Comment: Obviously, running container as root user is not very advisable practice. To run as non-root user you could add these commands to Dockerfile: `RUN groupadd -r appgroup && useradd -r -g appgroup appuser && chown -R appuser:appgroup /usr/local/tomcat/webapps /usr/local/tomcat/conf /usr/local/tomcat/logs && chown -R appuser:appgroup /mybusinessapp` newline `USER appuser`.