# How to use docker-compose with with tomcat

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a tomcat server. I need to edit some of the files within the docker container and want to know is there a way I can save these files so that if we're to do docker-compose up again on another machine it was used the edited files? One idea I had was to take the tomcat image to modify it then use the custom image in docker-compose. Or am I just overthinking this and having the edit those files manually is something that I just have to do. Also, I am relatively new to docker so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: " One idea I had was to take the tomcat image to modify it then use the custom image in docker-compose": yes, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using your own custom version of the tomcat image is the simplest way to configure it to your specifications.

See for instance, as example of configurations:

- "[Docker tomcat editing configuration files through dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541060/6309)"
- "[How to change user config in docker tomcat 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006845/6309)"